# How to find not used dependencies in Bazel build file?

Tags: build, dependencies, bazel

Suppose I've a Bazel package with a BUILD.bazel file that contains a list of dependencies. Some dependencies are not in use anymore. How to find the dependencie that are not in use ?

This is a Java project but I think the language is not important.

Comment: [unused_deps](https://blog.bazel.build/2017/06/28/sjd-unused_deps.html#unused_deps) you can find the not used dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[unused_deps](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/blob/master/unused_deps/README.md) works for Java projects. There is no tool that works for all languages. For C++ a pattern like [IWYU](https://github.com/storypku/bazel_iwyu) can help to decide when and how to make a dependency.